# UITableViewCell scroll over custom UITableView header title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple `UITableViewController` which contains about 40 `UITableViewCells` and the `UITableViewController` is embedded in a `UITabBarController`. The `UITableViewController` is created in Storyboard.

I am overriding the custom `UITableViewHeader` Text so that I can have a few guides there for users. I am noticing some really weird behaviour with this as represented by the following images:

[image]

[image]

As can be seen, the `UITableView` scrolls, but the header text remains there and it looks terrible.

Here is how I'm setting up the custom header:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Custom label for the section header titles
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 110)];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;

    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]];

    if (section == 0)
    {
        label.text = @" Add to this by marking a leaflet or video as a favourite.\n\nYou can do this by swiping left on any leaflet or video cell.";
    }    
    return label;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    CGFloat headerHeight = 0;

    headerHeight = 110;

    return headerHeight;

}
```

I have worked with different sizes, but no matter what I do, it still behaves in the same way.

If anyone has any thoughts or guidance on this, that would really be appreciated. I just want the header text to also scroll up with the table view and to therefore be hidden from view when scrolling.

Comment: it is lable background Color issue. Just set the label.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor]; in viewForHeaderInSection.

Comment: Thanks @Dev.RK - the accepted answer worked in this case without needing to change the background colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your header as the `tableHeaderView` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 110)];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]];
    label.text = @" Add to this by marking a leaflet or video as a favourite.\n\nYou can do this by swiping left on any leaflet or video cell.";
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = label;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @lorenzoiliveto - I had no idea I could do this and with your code in the viewDidLoad instead of separately overriding the method, this fixed the issue. Thanks again for your quick help with this!

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Custom label for the section header titles
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 110)];
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 110)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.numberOfLines = 0;

[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]];

if (section == 0) {
    label.text = @" Add to this by marking a leaflet or video as a favourite.\n\nYou can do this by swiping left on any leaflet or video cell.";
}    
[view addSubView:label];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; // the color for background
return view;}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @vaibby - that's really helpful but the other accepted answer worked in this case. Thanks again

Comment: u can give green tick for answer too.